# Why is Flash/Firefox abandoning HttpServiceRequests... sometimes?

Tags: flash, firefox

This just started recently.  As soon as the .SWF loads I hit 2 servlets on the same server.  My app still works perfectly in Chrome and IE.

But in Firefox I am getting 2302 streaming errors.  Opening Firebug shows that I am getting responses with HTTP 200.  But the content length does not get up to the length specified in the header most of the time.  It's like Firefox just quits trying.  Occasionally it will work.

Any ideas?

(I tried Firefox safe mode without any luck.)

Comment: The Firefox browser does not handle Flash, it's just a plugin.

Comment: Firefox still makes the web requests.  They show up in firebug.  Also, as I said, this works in IE and Chrome with Flash Player.  Pretty ridiculous down-vote.

Comment: Also @mate64, I just downgraded my firefox to 39.03 and this worked fine.  Unfortunately, I can't make my customers do that, so I still need an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by an update in Firefox 40 and was resolved last night by a hotfix. Firefox Bugzilla #1196000.

I was also given this advice by someone on the Mozilla team that should have worked as a workaround before the fix was applied:

Set about:config > dom.ipc.plugins.asyncInit = false as local workaround.

EDIT: I just tested the beta and FF41 will work with this set to true.